# Sheet selection from dropdown

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a sheet "PO", which holds data for google docs template. After a doc from template is generated, all data from that sheet goes into another sheet "Project 01" (a register of all POs for that project).

With the code that I have, I can only do this with one Project sheet with `getSheetbyName`, but I need to do this for multiple projects, that is, PO data needs to go the appropriate project.

Ideally, I would like to have a dropdown with sheet names, where the data will be copied to the appropriate sheet if the names match in the dropdown. How would I accomplish this?

My code:

```
var sss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('ahkj54IIndlskdjf123hdUTS'); 
var ss = sss.getSheetByName('PO');
var range = ss.getRange('A2:I50');
var data = range.getValues();

var tss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('78udjUdklo78354fghUjdlIWS24Chf');
var ts = tss.getSheetByName('Project 01'); 

ts.getRange(ts.getLastRow()+1, 1,49,9).setValues(data);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created the data validation manually.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  //e.source.toast('entry');
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  const shts = ['Sheet1','Sheet2','Sheet3','Sheet4'];
  const idx = shts.indexOf(e.value)
  if(sh.getName() == 'Sheet0' && e.range.columnStart == 1 && e.range.rowStart > 1 && ~idx) {
    let tsh = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName(shts[idx]);
    sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart,1,1,sh.getLastColumn()).copyTo(tsh.getRange(tsh.getLastRow() + 1,1));
  }
}
```

Sheet0:(aftter two operations):

| COL1 | COL2 | COL3 | COL4 | COL5 | COL6 | COL7 | COL8 | COL9 | COL10 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Sheet1 | 1,2 | 1,3 | 1,4 | 1,5 | 1,6 | 1,7 | 1,8 | 1,9 | 1,10 |
| Sheet4 | 2,2 | 2,3 | 2,4 | 2,5 | 2,6 | 2,7 | 2,8 | 2,9 | 2,10 |
|  | 3,2 | 3,3 | 3,4 | 3,5 | 3,6 | 3,7 | 3,8 | 3,9 | 3,10 |
|  | 4,2 | 4,3 | 4,4 | 4,5 | 4,6 | 4,7 | 4,8 | 4,9 | 4,10 |

Sheet 1:

| Sheet1 | 1,2 | 1,3 | 1,4 | 1,5 | 1,6 | 1,7 | 1,8 | 1,9 | 1,10 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |

Sheet4:

| Sheet4 | 2,2 | 2,3 | 2,4 | 2,5 | 2,6 | 2,7 | 2,8 | 2,9 | 2,10 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I modified your validation to my needs, but, obviously, not correctly, because no matter what I do, I get "TypeError: Cannot read property 'getSheet' of undefined". I guess I am not defining the source properly?

Comment: Perhaps you are trying to run the onEdit(e) function without supplying the event object.  I normally develop these by editing the appropriate sheet and see what happens. In this case my sheet name is Sheet0.

Comment: Hi, tried to play with this, but still not able to get it work. Copied your code, made Sheet0 (source), Sheet1, Sheet2, Sheet3, and Sheet4, but nothing happens when data is entered in Sheet0. The log says: TypeError: Cannot read property 'range' of undefined
onEdit @ Code.gs:3. Thanks

Comment: I hope that you realize that you cannot call an onEdit function without supplying the event object.  It's sound like that is what you attempting to do.  So unless you have created an intermediate function which creates the event object then you can't called onEdit functions from the script editor.

Comment: I remember testing this before I gave it to you.  I build these function by editing the appropriate sheet in order to initiate the onedit trigger.

Comment: I just tested it again and it works fine for me.

Comment: I set the validation manual for the following list  `Sheet1,Sheet2,Sheet3,Sheet4`

Comment: Sorry, yes, it works, I was just expecting different behaviour. Thank you, I'll build on this.